# I have to make an array of strings from multiple inputs in Vuejs. How can I go about this?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[image]

The above picture is how it looks like.

Now, from every input time value, I have to create an array: timeSlots:["600", "1200", "1500"] like so, when submit is clicked.

I know I can data bind each input using v-model, and then when submit is clicked I can loop over them and add them to an array.

But is there a better way to this, especially using v-for ?

For example, if I have like 40 slots, having 40 data variables doesn't look great in the code.

Comment: Use an array to contain all the data, and bind to the specific index in your loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use arrays with your `v-model` via `v-model="timeSlot[index]"`. Now you can assign a specific value to `timeSlot[index]`. Any changes made to this input are reflected in your array -- including removing it. You can also submit this data as an array to your server.

There is a caveat to using `index` (ideally, the key should be something unique) in your loop to bind your data back to your array. While simple data like in the example **should** behave properly objects, or components, with complex data that need to be reactive may not be. You can check out this article for more info: https://deepsource.io/blog/key-attribute-vue-js/

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    timeSlots: [],
  },
  methods: {
    addSlot() {
      this.timeSlots.push('');
    },
    removeSlot(index) {
      this.timeSlots.splice(index, 1);
    },
    submit() {
      // If using axios
      axios.post('/your-endpoing', { timeslots: this.timeSlots })
        .then(response => {
          // Response from server
        })
        .catch(error => {
          // Any erros
        })
        .finally(() => {
        
        });
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(slot, index) in timeSlots" :key="index">
    <input type="text" v-model="timeSlots[index]">
    <button type="button" @click="removeSlot(index)">&times;</button>
  </div>
  <button type="button" @click="addSlot">Add Slot</button>
  <h3>Output</h3>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(slot, index) in timeSlots" :key="index">{{ slot }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always create a variable which will hold the values and loop over it and bind the loop variable with `v-model` like that

```
<template>
  <div style="display: flex">
    <div 
      v-for="(slot, key) in timeSlots" 
      :key="key" 
    >
      <input 
        type="text" 
        v-model="slot.value" 
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data: () => ({
    timeSlots: [
      {value: "600"}, 
      {value: "1200"}, 
      {value: "1500"}
    ]
  }),
  components: {
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```